# how do you select the entry with the max value in coredata?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

for example, I have a managed object save in coredata like

@interface team : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic)NSNumber* teamID;

@end

I have successfully saved some teams with unique teamID in coredata, now I want to get the team with the max teamID, how do I do this?

I used to get all teams and sort them, but this would bring large overhead to make the fetched array, any better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `NSExpression` is one of the ways to do so. This has been described with a complete example under the `Fetching Specific Values` section in [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)

Comment: yes, I used @"@max:", so that it could use filter of MySQL instead of fetch all result and then filter in memory, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use an `NSSortDescriptor` for your fetch request using NSFetchRequests's `-setSortDescriptors:` method to specify an order for fetching objects.
2. Specify a fetch limit using NSFetchRequest's `-setFetchLimit:` to get only the first object.

Answer (score 0):

user465191,

Here's what I do:

```
NSNumber *max = [teams valueForKeyPath: @"@max.teamID"];

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", @"teamID", max];

Team *team = [[teams filteredSetUsingPredicate: p] anyObject];
```

It is more cumbersome than I desire but it does work.

Andrew